# Linq to Entity Select, Exclude 1st result row?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a Linq to Entity Select statement that is currently returning all rows from the database.  Since the 1st row of data contains header information, is it possible to exclude the first row from the result set?

```
var surveyProgramType = surveyProgramTypeRepository
                        .Find()
                        .OrderBy(x => x.ProgramType);
```

Comment: Why do you have header information mixed in with your other data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `.Skip()`

```
var surveyProgramType = surveyProgramTypeRepository
    .Find()
    .OrderBy(x => x.ProgramType)
    .Skip(1);
```

Comment: I was getting an error until I put the .Skip(1) after the .OrderBy.  If you wouldn't mind editing your answer I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var surveyProgramType = surveyProgramTypeRepository
    .Find()
    .OrderBy(x => x.ProgramType).Skip(1);
```